# join two tables when one has null values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null

[image]

I want to list employees along with their jobs from job tables(use job_id key) but some employees have null as their job id and when i use join null values dont show up. i want the employees with no job ids to have null as their job designation. how do i do it?

Here is what i have tried

```
select EMP_ID,MANAGER_EMP_ID,FNAME||' '||LNAME as EMP_FULL_NAME,
HIRE_DATE as EMP_JOINING,salary as EMP_SALARY,function as
EMP_DESIGNATION from employee e join job j on e.job_id=j.job_id
```

Comment: You need to use a left outer join; [read up on the types of join in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries006.htm).

Comment: i knew about left join.. just that my concepts were a bit muddled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just change `join` to `left join`...

Comment: LOL. hmm big conception about left join got cleared :D. thanks. will accept ur answer in 10 minutes.